What is the problem with installing ClustalO?
I am trying to install clustalO in my python Colab notebook and I'm following the instructions on the website and I'm still getting errors. I've tried looking up multiple alternate ways to solve this online.
input: 
pip install clustalo

output: 
Collecting clustalo
  Using cached clustalo-0.1.2.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: clustalo
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for clustalo (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for clustalo
  Running setup.py clean for clustalo
Failed to build clustalo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for clustalo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


I'm not sure if doing it manually would be better/ more helpful but I was able to download the files from https://github.com/benchling/clustalo-python and I am still not able to install and run it.

have you tried installing locally? It seems like it's trying to compile from source at install, and colab doesn't have the build chain. If you install locally, there seem to be pre-built binaries on the link you provided.

reading more into it, what you attempted to install is just a wrapper which calls a separately installed program. Colab is failing to build the wrapper likely due to missing c compilation toolchain, but even if it did compile, you wouldn't have the actual program that the wrapper calls. It seems like the intent is very much to use linux either natively, or you could probably get away with virtualization like WSL.

Hi Aaron, thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it. Sorry, but I have no idea what much of your second comment means haha... is there an easy way to solve this issue? Like if I used a jupyter notebook instead?

Basically for various reasons Linux is sometimes better for programming, and an easy way to use Linux for Windows users is the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). A full explanation is too long for just a comment, but you should be able to look up tutorials to install WSL on your computer. then you should follow the installation instructions for clustalo itself to install it onto linux, and finally install the python package again specifically on your linux environment. this is mostly command line stuff. A different IDE won't really help.
